# Setting up 2 different animations for one one artboard - Adobe XD

Tags: adobe-xd

Im getting confused with my XD animation. What I want to do is make a tick bounce and have trees moving behind the truck rolling through creating the illusion of movement. I can only for some reason get the artboards to do one action or another. Not 2 simultaneously. I tried to create another wire that connects to the other artboard with a different function but it still just makes them do the same animation.

[image]

These are the x2 interactions set up for the Confirmation Page

[image]

[image]

This is the interaction for the confirmation 3 page. Its set to bounce right now for the tick I tried to add another wire for the trees but it still applied the same animation for both

[image]